# Stopping page to refresh when button is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have a button on a page, so every time I click it the onclick code runs and then the page refreshes.  Earlier it was working fine but now it has started refreshing page.

As the `input type is submit` now, it refreshes page but if I make the `input type to button`, it does not refreshes my page but my bootstrap validation on input elements does not work.

So I need my validations to work as well as the page should not be refresh automatically.

Below is my code.

```
$("#btn-payment").click(function(){

    if($('#select-GenAccount').val() !="" && $('#input-transactionID').val() != "" && $('#select-transactionType').val() != "" &&                       $('#input-transactionDate').val() != "" && $('#input-BankName').val() != "" && $('#input-AccountName').val() != "" && $('#input-Amount').val() != "")
    {
        if(parseInt($("#input-OutBalance").val()) >= parseInt($("#input-Amount").val()))
            {
                $("#div-paymentError").css('display','none');
                BootstrapDialog.show({
                    cssClass: 'login-dialog',
                    title: 'Confirmation',
                    message: 'Are you sure you want to make a part payment entry?',
                    buttons: [{
                        label: 'Yes',
                        action: function(dialog) {

                           dialog.close();                              
                           GetUserProfileData().done(function(returnedValue)
                           {
                                    CreateListItemPayment(returnedValue, 'Part_Payment');
                            }
                        }, {
                        label: 'No',
                        action: function(dialog) {
                            dialog.close();
                        }
                    }]
                }); 
            }
            else
            {
                $("#div-paymentError").text("Amount entered can not be more then outstanding balance");
                $("#div-paymentError").css('display','inline-block');
            }
        }
    });
```

Html for button

```
<input id="btn-payment" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" style="margin-left: 0px;">
```

Comment: Also I have other form, and on submit everything works fine and the page does not refresh as well. So I am not able to figure out what went wrong with this form.

Answer (score 5):

This might help you

```
$("#btn-payment").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

   //your code goes here.
   return false;
})
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is: Use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`

```
<input id="btn-payment" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Submit" style="margin-left: 0px;">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
e.preventDefault(); add it in your js will stop refreshing your page. 

<form name="formname" onsubmit="return false">
```

Answer (score 1):

Let getData() return false. This will fix it.

```
<form method="POST">
   <button name="data" onclick="return getData()">Click</button>
</form>
```